# Need a solution for bundler error "you must supply exec_name (ArgumentError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, passenger

A recent OS X Mojave update messed up my development environment. The mysql2 gem stopped working due to a conflict with openssl, and my applications couldn't access the database. After a bit of work I got them running except for one. I'm getting this strange error from bundler:

> you must supply exec_name (ArgumentError)

A Google search doesn't return very much. I can find the line of code where this comes from, but I can't determine the cause. It seems like a parameter isn't being passed correctly. Has anyone encountered this error before? Do you have a solution?

I'm running OS X Mojave 10.14.6, brew, apache, rbenv, Phusion Passenger, bundler 2.1.4. I was initially on Ruby 2.5.1 and tried 2.5.2, but it didn't make a difference.

Here's the full output:

```
     (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
     Compilation successful. The logs are here:
     /var/folders/dz/w4nlmkh15zd2w58p748jqhf40000gn/T/passenger_native_support-15m6n7c.log
 [passenger_native_support.bundle] successfully loaded.
Error: The application encountered the following error: you must supply exec_name (ArgumentError)
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:362:in `block in replace_bin_path'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:413:in `block in replace_bin_path'
    /Users/someuser/Sites/somedomain.localhost/config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb:38:in `<module:WickedPdfHelper>'
    /Users/someuser/Sites/somedomain.localhost/config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:663:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:662:in `load_config_initializer'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:620:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `each'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:619:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    /Users/someuser/Sites/somedomain.localhost/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    config.ru:1:in `new'
    config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.4_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.4_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.4_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.4_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.4_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.4_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/6.0.4_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Gem env:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.2 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 104) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/someuser/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/someuser/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /Users/someuser/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/someuser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Users/someuser/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

The apache v-host entry for the troubled application:

````
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin here@there.com
    ServerName somedomain.localhost
    ServerAlias www.somedomain.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/someuser/Sites/somedomain.localhost/public
    PassengerRuby /Users/someuser/.rbenv/shims/ruby

    ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/error_log
    <Directory /Users/someuser/Sites/somedomain.localhost/public>
        Options -Multiviews
        # ^ for Apache 2.4+
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        #Require all granted
        RailsEnv development
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin here@there.com
    ServerName somedomain.localhost
    ServerAlias www.somedomain.localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/someuser/Sites/somedomain.localhost/public

    PassengerRuby /Users/someuser/.rbenv/shims/ruby
    PassengerAppEnv "development"
    PassengerMinInstances 1

    ErrorLog /private/var/log/apache2/error_log
    <Directory /Users/someuser/Sites/somedomain.localhost>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes Authconfig

        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/somedomain.localhost/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/somedomain.localhost/server.key"
</VirtualHost>```
````

Comment: It appears to be a bundler error, has your version of bundler changed? I sometimes get warnings from Heroku that my bundler was updated and if I experience issues I should try going back to the old version. Or reinstall bundler and build again?

Comment: Your question must include steps to reproduce the issue. In this case, you're saying you get a given error from bundler, but how do you actually get this error? bundler does a LOT of things -- until you include (at the absolute minimum) the actual command you're entering to generate this error, I'm not sure anyone can help you.

Comment: I did try some different versions of Bundler, but I received the same error message. Bundler 2.1.4 works on other development computers that I have, so I'm stumped why this one is having issues.

As far as replicating this issue, this is a pretty basic Rails application. I've already listed the software versions, but I'm thinking there is something specific to my system that is broken. Why one Rails application works and not another is very odd. I'll probably end up reinstalling the OS and starting from zero. This all happened because of a Mojave update, so who knows what that did.

Comment: The issue was caused by some code in an initializer. You can see a few lines down in the error log where it shows "initializers/wicked_pdf.rb:38". I re-generated the initializer for the wicked_pdf gem and the app started working normally. I'm not sure why it didn't want to run on this computer since it runs on another with the exact same OS and app software.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a breaking change in bundler 2.1 that you can learn more about by viewing the [Pull Request](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/pull/7075).

The change is designed to prevent you from loading the wrong executable when calling `Gem.bin_path`.  Suppose 2 gems (`myGem` and `yourGem`) contain executables with the same name, `run-my-program`.  Calling `Gem.bin_path("run-my-program")` is ambiguous--which executable do you want it to load?

This is a major security risk--you might be running one executable, thinking you are running another.

To avoid this ambiguity, bundler now forces you to specify which gem you want to load the executable from whenever you call `Gem.bin_path`:

```
Gem.bin_path(
  'myGem', # Ensures you load the executable from myGem instead of yourGem
  'the-executable-name'
)
```

Check your source code (you stacktrace suggests a good starting point is `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`) for any calls to `Gem.bin_path`, `Gem.activate_bin_path`, or `Gem.find_spec_for_exe` and make sure you are passing 2 second arguments: the name of the gem you want to load the executable from, followed by the name of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
After a system upgrade, my bundler version was `2.1.4`, downgrading to `2.0.2` solved the issue.